# Saving and retrieving a struct which is not codable to Userdefaults in Swift

Tags: swift, userdefaults, custom-object

I want to save a struct which can not be modified to `UserDefaults` in my code. I went through a number of solutions but everyone is advising to use `Codable/NSCoding` in the *struct*. I can not edit the struct. Does anyone have an idea how we can achieve this.

I tried to wrap the object to an `NSDictionary` but while trying to save, it crashes saying '*Attempt to insert non-property list object*'. Is it because I have nil values in my model?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [edit] your question to include the `struct` definition. Why can't you add `Codable` conformance in an `extension`?

Comment: Event if this structure was defined in separate module you had no access you can extend it to be `Codable`.

Comment: @Astoria: It is giving me the error 'Implementation of 'Decodable' cannot be automatically synthesized in an extension in a different file to the type' and Implementation of 'Encodable' cannot be automatically synthesized in an extension in a different file to the type. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @iOSManiac implement the protocol methods yourself

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change your `struct`, then create an `extension` for it and conform it to `Codable`.

Once conformed to `Codable`, you can use `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` to convert to and from data and then save/retrieve from `UserDefaults`.

```
struct Sample {
    var name = "Sample Struct"
}

extension Sample: Codable {

}

let obj = Sample()
let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(obj)

//Saving in UserDefaults
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "SampleStruct")

//Fetching from UserDefaults
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "SampleStruct") {
    let val = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Sample.self, from: data)
    print(val) //Sample(name: "Sample Struct")
}
```

Comment: Since it is in a different file I am getting error like  'Implementation of 'Decodable' cannot be automatically synthesized in an extension in a different file to the type' and Implementation of 'Encodable' cannot be automatically synthesized in an extension in a different file to the type.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to wrap the object to an NSDictionary

You can't save a custom model without conforming to `Codable/NSCoding` , if you don't need to conform then save it as a usual `Array/Dictionary` without wrapping any custom objects inside